# Return columns from one table that doesn't exist on another

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to verify if some columns from one table are present on anothers.

For example, i have a

> table A

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| ... | ... |

and a

> table B

| w | x |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| ... | ... |

The final output should be:

> column w

Is this possible?

Comment: you mean the values in the columns?

Comment: not the values, i really mean the columns. This's because i have a table with almost 100 columns and anothers with lot of columns too, and i have to insert data from a table to another, and some of the columns are identically on both tables and others not, so i have to check which columns are relevant from each table and which columns i want to insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` and `MINUS`.  Like so:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM   all_tab_columns 
WHERE  owner = 'whoever owns TABLE_A'
AND    table_name = 'TABLE_A'
MINUS
SELECT column_name
FROM   all_tab_columns 
WHERE  owner = 'whoever owns TABLE_B'
AND    table_name = 'TABLE_B'
```

This will return the names of any column that exists in `TABLE_A` but not `TABLE_B`.

Comment: the table or view dba_tab_columns does not exist

Comment: It does exist, you probably just don't have access.  Use 'ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` instead.

Comment: edit your answer with 'ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`, it worked for me

Comment: i just removed the owner condition

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and straightforward way to check for the column in a table is to use the information schema for column system view. Write a select query for INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as shown below. If the query returns record, then the column is available in the table.
`USE {{Database Name}} SELECT *  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  WHERE TABLE_NAME = '{{Table Name}}' AND COLUMN_NAME = '{{Column Name}}'`

Comment: Please imporove the sql code formatting. Each statement on one line at a min.  
USE

SELECT
FROM
WHERE
AND